# How to create multiple-sub "where" "in" queries in flask_sqlalchemy or SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy so bear a bit with me if the question is not properly articulated.

But I have a particular problem I would like to solve.
Let say we have a parent, child, and toy table. Where we have a m2m relationship between family-parent, parent-child and child-toy.

Now if we would like to gather all family in which a toy is present ( a child can be part of the parent family and grandparents family) we would do:

```
select * from family where parent_id in ( select parent_id from parent where child_id in (select child_id from child where toy_id in (1,2)))
```

And I would like to convert this to a `SQLAlchemy` or `flask_sqlalchemy` query.
One way I know of is to do something like :

```
Toy.query.filter(Toy.id.in_((1, 2))).all()
```

Or in pure SQLAlchemy:

```
session.query(Toy).filter(Toy.id.in_((1, 2))).all()
```

Then get the output put it into a list comprehension and use the list as the input of another where in.

But this feels very inefficient as the query would be evaluated on each filter/list comprehension creation.

Is there any way to have this query in a single `flask_sqlalchemy`  or just pure `SQLAlchemy`command, in such a way that it can be evaluated only once?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use subquery:

```
ch = session.query(Child.child_id).filter(Child.toy_id.in_([1,2])).subquery('ch')
p = session.query(Parent.parent_id).filter(Parent.child_id.in_(ch)).subquery('p')
result = session.query(Family).filter(Family.parent_id.in_(p)).all()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually create a filter_list, and then execute the query at once as you described

```
filter_list = list()
filter_list.append(Child.toy_id.in_([1,2]))
filter_list.append(Child.toy_id.in_([4,5]))  # some other condition...
# more conditions here...
result = session.query(Child).filter(*filter_list).all()
```

the *filter_list syntax automatically applies all the conditions you appended to the filter_list

Comment: Though this is technically correct (and pythonic), the computation is happening on the python side instead of the db side. Moving compute (and memory costs) to your db side via subqueries will result in dramatically better performance.

Comment: I have reason to believe this isnt correct, because I can print the sql query that this statement creates: `result = session.query(Child).filter(*filter_list)` (notice the .all() is missing), and it includes the where statement like any native sql query (executed by the db) would. I guess you confused the sqlalchemy .filter() statement with the python standard library .filter() method? session.query().filter() is all working on the sqlalchemy database abstration layer library.

Comment: Great point, that `.filter()` is an sql command, not python native. My comment is more directed to the creation and storage of filter statements (ex: `Child.toy_id.in_([1,2])`) --> if these statements are dependent on other sql queries and/or become large, performance will begin to suffer. Better to conduct these in sql with orm on the db side.

Comment: this *is* using the ORM, have you checked the documentation? docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html  . These methods are just query-builders (ORM-level SQL construction object), all the sql is obviously happening on the db side. I really dont think the python side performance will suffer at doing this, or at least it is quite literally exactly what sqlalchemy is meant to do...

Comment: Fair points. And thanks for pointing me towards the docs. lemme give them a deeper read.